# Excel Interop : Can you listen for a change in range value?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, range, excel-interop

Is it possible, and if so how, to listen to changes in an Excel range from within C# using the MS interop libraries?

I know how to read the value in a named range, but don't know how to listen and automatically pick up changes. Been through Google and not found anything to solve this...

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? Show your effort first.. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: *le sigh* I've trawled through the GOOG and played with the API but havn't managed to do it. Maybe I'm missing somehting simple though. Is that OK?

Comment: Depends on what you exactly want to do... Not sure if you have seen this link? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823981

Comment: Thanks I'll use this and Mitja's advice - should get the job done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Range object has a Change event. You can listen to the Worksheet Change event and probably do a bit more checking to figure out if the change is the one you want to catch.